# Linking to JVM asm-defined classes from Kotlin using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, jasmin

I have the following setup for an Android app:

```
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── AndroidManifest.xml
        ├── asm
        │   └── SomeJVMClass.j
        ├── kotlin
        │   └── activity.kt
        └── res
            └── values
                └── strings.xml
```

The source file in `src/main/asm/SomeJVMClass.j` is [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) format JVM assembly (it's almost the same as Jasmin). I would like to use the class it defines from my main Kotlin source `activity.kt`.

Before I even get to trying to automate this with Gradle, just assembling the file manually into `build` doesn't help. Here's what I tried:

1. Do a `gradle build` to get the skeleton `build` directory (this of course fails with the Kotlin compiler not finding `SomeJVMClass`)
2. I run Krakatau manually to put its class files in  `build/intermediates/classes/{debug,release}`:

   ```
   $ for flavor in debug release; do ~/prog/jvm/krakatau/assemble.py -out build/intermediates/classes/$flavor -r src/main/asm ;done

   Processing file src/main/asm/SomeJVMClass.j, 1/1 remaining
   Class written to build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/JVMServer/SomeJVMClass.class

   Processing file src/main/asm/SomeJVMClass.j, 1/1 remaining
   Class written to build/intermediates/classes/release/com/example/JVMServer/SomeJVMClass.class
   ```
3. Re-run `grade build` with the hope that Kotlin will now find the `.class`files; but no improvement whatsoever:

> ```
> :compileDebugKotlin
> e: /home/cactus/prog/android/kotlin-asm/src/main/kotlin/activity.kt (3,20): 
>    Unresolved reference: JVMServer
> e: /home/cactus/prog/android/kotlin-asm/src/main/kotlin/activity.kt: (12,14): 
>    Unresolved reference: SomeJVMClass
> ```

So the first question is, obviously, where do I put the resulting `.class` files so that the Kotlin compiler can find them. And the second, follow-up question, is how do I automate that so that a single `gradle build` command will run the Krakatau assembler first, before running the Kotlin compiler.

For reference, here are my source files:

`src/main/asm/SomeJVMClass.j`:

```
.class public com/example/JVMServer/SomeJVMClass
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static foo: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  .code stack 2 locals 0
    ldc "JVM bytecode works"
    areturn
  .end code
.end method

.end class
```

`src/main/kotlin/activity.kt`:

```
package com.example.JVMClient

import com.example.JVMServer.SomeJVMClass    
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity: Activity() {
  protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setTitle(SomeJVMClass.foo())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: turns out this approach does not work for android-gradle**

This is more related to gradle than Kotlin, you can tell gradle to include `.class` files during compilation by adding the statement `compile files("build/intermediates/classes/debug")` to your dependencies.

This will place the .class files on the classpath where Kotlin should be able to find them.

Comment: Sounds promising, but then I get `Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: build/intermediates/classes/debug` from `:prepareDebugDependencies`

Comment: Moreover, if I put my `SomeJVMClass.class` file in a `.jar` and use     `compile files("build/intermediates/classes/debug/asm.jar")`, it fails later in `:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` with `Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/example/JVMServer/SomeJVMClass`

Comment: @Cactus Putting it as a .jar file in the build directory might trigger an automatic include, try removing the compile line but leaving the .jar

Comment: Nope, then it's back to `:compileDebugKotlin` not finding `JVMServer'

Comment: @Cactus One solution I can think of is to create a gradle subproject as a normal java library project, including the .class files in the output of that project and the adding a dependency to that subproject. Because it seems android has removed some of the capabilities of gradle's dependency system.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Gradle... do you have an example of such a subproject setup? Ideally including the actual assembly step as part of the build process as well.

Comment: @Cactus refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html for subprojects and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html for custom tasks.

Comment: @Cactus This documentation might actually solve your problem: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html